# problem scrolling a pageview in a tab view in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

in my flutter app, I have a tab bar with two tabs and in one of the tab views I have a pageview .for changing the pages in page view I need a horizontal scroll but in some devices when I try to slide the pages the tab is changing instead but in other devices its Ok. what can I do to solve this problem?

```
    TabBarView(
        controller: this.tabController,
        children: [
            SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                        50.vertical,
                        Container(
                            width: context.getWidth(0.9, 240, 480),
                            child: Stack(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                    GetBuilder<PagesController>(
                                        tag: '@inspiration',
                                        builder: (_controller) {
                                            Obx o = Obx(() => CardScrollWidget(
                                                currentPage: (sgetter.list.length -
                                                    1 -(tabchanged ? 0 : pageController.page)).toDouble(),
                                                widgetAspectRatio: widgetAspectRatio,
                                                cardAspectRatio: cardAspectRatio,
                                                recipes: sgetter.list));
                                                tabchanged = false;
                                            return o;
                                            }),
                            Positioned.directional(
                                start: 25.w,
                                end: 35.h,
                                top: 50.h,
                            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                            child: SizedBox(
                                height: cardAspectRatio * context.width - 190.w,
                              
                                child: PageView.builder(
                                    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                    itemCount: sgetter.list.length,
                                    controller: pageController.controller,
                                    onPageChanged: (index) {
                                        sendRequestPageChange(sgetter);
                                        pageController.controller.animateToPage(index,
                                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                                        curve: Curves.linearToEaseOut);
                                    },
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                        return GestureDetector(
                                            onTap: () => Get.to(() => RecipeScreen(
                                            id: sgetter
                                                .list[sgetter.list.length -
                                                    index -
                                                    1]
                                                    .id,
                                            imageUrl: sgetter
                                                .list[sgetter.list.length -
                                                    index -
                                                    1]
                                                    .imgUrl,
                                            onRated: (int value) {
                                                sgetter
                                                    .list[sgetter.list.length -
                                                        index -
                                                        1]
                                                        .rate = value;
                                                Get.find<SuggestionsGetter>().get();
                                           
                                            },
                                        )),
                                        child: Container(
                                            color: Colors.transparent,
                                        ),
                                        );
                                    },
                                ),
                            )),
                        LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
                            pageController.pageViewInitialized = true;
                            return SizedBox.shrink();
                        })
                      ],
                    ),
                ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            PantryScreen(),
        ]
),
```

Comment: is it possible to just disable tab views slide behavior but the page view work with horizontal sliding?

Answer (score 0):

You can `disable` tabView scroll, like this:

```
TabBarView(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        controller: this.tabController,
        children: [...]
      ),
```